# Generating Custom Telerik RadFilter Query

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Okay, so one of my tasks for today is to modify an existing Telerik RadFilter on a client's website. The filter itself allows the user to perform queries on a Telerik RadGrid. This is all well and good, however the client wants this filtering made easier in the form of a comma-separated list.

```
<!-- The new comma-separated list text box -->
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuery" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnQuery" runat="server" Text="Filter By List" />

<!-- The existing RadFilter -->
<telerik:RadFilter runat="server" ID="AttendeesGridFilter" Visible="true"
    FilterContainerID="AttendeesGrid" ShowApplyButton="false" />
```

Basically the AttendeesGrid (RadGrid) this looks at contains various columns about event attendees. This comma separated list will allow the user to quickly filter by attendee ID in bulk. The way I figured I'd do this is by pulling the content of txtQuery, putting it into a list of sorts and firing it back at the RadFilter so that an entry of 1, 2, 3, 4 would generate something like this:

[image]

Is this actually possible? If so, could anyone point me in the right direction to how I'd generate a custom RadFilter query from the back-end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you start in the right direction, I've done something similar this week with my code, I've had to remove some of the object names and contents before posting.

What I did:

- radgrid with a need DataSource
- moved the datasource fetching to a new function and call this function from the needDataSource
- a filter (radtextbox) and button that trigger a custom filter by calling the custom datasource fetcher & rebinding the grid
- attach everything to the radAjax Manager (not shown) to avoid the full page refresh

RadGrid

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server" ></telerik:RadTextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdvSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnCommand="FilterBySearch" />
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid1" EnableAJAX="True" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="radGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="radGrid1_ItemDataBound">
...
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

My code behind I've moved the DataFetching into it's own function so that it can be called from several places rather than just on needDataSource

```
protected void radGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    SetGridDatasource();
}
```

The search button will trigger this function which gets the source and rebinds the grid

```
protected void FilterBySearch(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    SetGridDatasource();
    radGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

The gridDataSource fetches the object from the DB and I use linq to filter out based on the search text passed in.

```
private void SetGridDatasource()
{
    var searchText = searchBox.Text.Trim();
    using (var db = new ContactsDataContext())
    {
        var DataObjectList = db.DataObjectGetByAccount(AccountId, 3).ToList();
        var filtered = (from list in DataObjectList where
            (list.DataObjectName.Contains(searchText) ||
            list.id.ToString().Contains(searchText) ||
            list.description.ToString().Contains(searchText))
            select list);

        rgDataObjects.DataSource = filtered;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Brian, this is pretty much what I ended up doing in the end. It wasn't a perfect solution but it worked and the client didn't seem too bothered. This answer looks pretty solid so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!